# Calculate highest word frequency across lines

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out this problem to no success, keep getting 3 errors. Basically the program is supposed to read a text file (see below) and calculate the highest frequency words.

My program is compared to an rspec to check my work, which is where I see the 3 errors. Where am I going wrong in the code to create the 3 errors?

**Text file (test.txt) that is read:**

This is a really really really cool experiment really
Cute little experiment
Will it work maybe it will work do you think it will it will

**Code I am running that shows 3 errors**:

```
class LineAnalyzer
      attr_accessor :highest_wf_count, :highest_wf_words, :content, :line_number #Implement the following read-only attributes in the LineAnalyzer class. 
  #* highest_wf_count - a number with maximum number of occurrences for a single word (calculated)
  #* highest_wf_words - an array of words with the maximum number of occurrences (calculated)
  #* content          - the string analyzed (provided)
  #* line_number      - the line number analyzed (provided)

  def initialize(content, line)   #Implement the initialize() method to:   #* take in a line of text and line number
      @content = content   #* initialize the content and line_number attributes
      @line_number = line   
      @highest_wf_count = 0
      @highest_wf_words = []
      calculate_word_frequency()  #* call the calculate_word_frequency() method.
  end

  def calculate_word_frequency() #potentially remove self (add in self because this is an instance method)
    word_frequency = Hash.new(0) #may have to remove parentheses zero
    content.split.each do |word|
      word_frequency[word.downcase] += 1
      @highest_wf_count = word_frequency.values.max       #* (may have to do parentheses after max) calculate the maximum number of times a single word appears within provided content and store that in the highest_wf_count attribute.
      @highest_wf_words = word_frequency.select {|k,v| v == @highest_wf_count} # (may have to do .keys at the end) can also do word_frequency.select {|k,v| v == @highest_wf_count}
    end  
      #* identify the words that were used the maximum number of times and store that in the highest_wf_words attribute.
  end
end


class Solution
  #may have to 'include Enumerable' here
  attr_reader :analyzers, :highest_count_across_lines, :highest_count_words_across_lines # Implement the following read-only attributes in the Solution class.
  #* highest_count_across_lines - a number with the maximum value for highest_wf_words attribute in the analyzers array.
  #* highest_count_words_across_lines - a filtered array of LineAnalyzer objects with the highest_wf_words attribute 
  #  equal to the highest_count_across_lines determined previously.

  def initialize() #may need to take out analyzers and just do parentheses
    @analyzers = [] #* analyzers - an array of LineAnalyzer objects for each line in the file. Can also do [] instead of Array.new
    @highest_count_across_lines = nil
    @highest_count_words_across_lines = nil
  end

  def analyze_file()
    File.foreach('test.txt').with_index(1) do |content, line|
      line_analyzer = LineAnalyzer.new(content, line)
      @analyzers << line_analyzer
    end
  end

  #* calculate the maximum value for highest_wf_count contained by the LineAnalyzer objects in analyzers array
  #  and stores this result in the highest_count_across_lines attribute.
  #* identifies the LineAnalyzer objects in the analyzers array that have highest_wf_count equal to highest_count_across_lines 
  #  attribute value determined previously and stores them in highest_count_words_across_lines.
  def calculate_line_with_highest_frequency()
    @highest_count_across_lines = analyzers.sort_by { |analyzer| analyzer.highest_wf_count }.reverse.first.highest_wf_count
    @highest_count_words_across_lines = analyzers.select { |k| v == @highest_count_across_lines }
  end

  #* print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines() - prints the values of LineAnalyzer objects in #  highest_count_words_across_lines in the specified format
  def print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines()  #* print the values of objects in highest_count_words_across_lines in the specified format
    "The following words have the highest frequency per line: \n  #{highest_count_words_across_lines} (appears in line #{line_num} \n"  
  end
end
```

**The three errors I get when I run the above code compared to the rspec**:

```
  1) Solution#analyze_file creates 3 line analyzers
     Failure/Error: expect(solution.analyzers.length).to eq 3

       expected: 3
            got: 12

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count across lines to be 4
     Failure/Error: solution.calculate_line_with_highest_frequency

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `v' for #<Solution:0x0000000003163098>
     # ./module2_assignment.rb:56:in `block in calculate_line_with_highest_frequency'
     # ./module2_assignment.rb:56:in `select'
     # ./module2_assignment.rb:56:in `calculate_line_with_highest_frequency'
     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
     Failure/Error: solution.calculate_line_with_highest_frequency

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `v' for #<Solution:0x0000000003937990>
     # ./module2_assignment.rb:56:in `block in calculate_line_with_highest_frequency'
     # ./module2_assignment.rb:56:in `select'
     # ./module2_assignment.rb:56:in `calculate_line_with_highest_frequency'
     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:36:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.31637 seconds (files took 0.94452 seconds to load)
19 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/solution_spec.rb:12 # Solution#analyze_file creates 3 line analyzers
rspec ./spec/solution_spec.rb:22 # Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count across lines to be 4
rspec ./spec/solution_spec.rb:31 # Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is here:

```
@highest_count_words_across_lines = analyzers.select { |k| v == @highest_count_across_lines }
```

Try:

```
@highest_count_words_across_lines = analyzers.select { |k, v| v == @highest_count_across_lines }
```

The Hash#select method uses two placeholders, k and v (key and value although you can call these whatever you like). If you're looking to check the value, you need to feed in both arguments.

More reading: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select

Comment: Thank you Mark! It now only shows 1 error: Failures:

  1) Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
     Failure/Error: expect(words_found).to match_array ["will", "it", "really"]

       expected collection contained:  ["it", "really", "will"]
       actual collection contained:    []
       the missing elements were:      ["it", "really", "will"]
     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'